# How to use more than one header in a php login page

Tags: php, laravel, http, backend

Below is my login page code in php.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // username and password sent from form 

  $myusername = $_POST['username'];
  $mypassword = $_POST['password']; 
  $f_password = md5($mypassword);

  $sql = "SELECT id,user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '$myusername' and password = '$f_password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {
      $_SESSION['us_name'] = $row['user_name'];
      header("Location: /main-page.php");
  }else {
     $error = "<script>alert('Incorrect Credentials.Please login again');</script>";
     echo $error;
  }
}
?>
```

When i use another header in else block it throws me some error .
But i want user to redirect to same login page when he enters wrong credentials.
How can I do it in php??
Please don't tell me to use js method window.location.

Comment: Surely "some error" is telling you what the problem is with whatever code you wrote?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: And don't use md5 for password encryption, it can easily be hacked using modern computing power - this was discovered quite a while back now. Instead use PHP's built in password hashing functions.

Comment: Lastly if you want to redirect when there's an error, then don't echo anything - 1) it will cause an error because you sent content before headers, and 2) what would be the point anyway? If the user is redirected they will never see that content.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question: I assume the error comes from sending data - the `echo` you do in the else block - and then trying to add headers. You must send all headers before sending the first data, which includes printing stuff with `echo`.

Your problem should go away if you put the `header()` line right in the beginning of the else block and make sure you have no other output before (e.g. with a `var_dump()`).

Additionally there is a number of security issues in your script:

- You use `md5()` to encode the password which is highly insecure. Modern php has a function [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (available since PHP 5.5) which you should use instead
- Your username and password are used without filtering the input. This opens you up to SQL injection as they are reused in an unsafe manner in your SQL query. You should look at prepared statements or at least filter and quote the user input

Another question related as to why you need the header: If you want to redirect to the login page, why do you have the `<script>`-snippet on the page? When changing the location it will not take affect anyway, right?

And final question, your question is tagged with laravel. So I'm curious why you don't use it's [Authentication mechanism](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users) instead?